# How can I use NSNotificationCenter to call a method in a second class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsnotificationcenter

I'm trying to use `NSNotificationCenter` to call a method in a second class but I'm getting an error:

second class method(request.m) :

```
-(void)getTheRequest:(NSString *)whereToCall;
```

and I'm trying to call it from `NSNotificationCenter` like this:

```
request *newRequest=[[request alloc]init];
[self performSelector:@selector(newRequest.getTheRequest:) withObject:@"mySite"];
```

but I'm getting a error in this part "newRequest.getTheRequest" it says "Expected Expression". Any of you know how I can fix this or how can I use `NSNotificationCenter` to call a methods in a different classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[newRequest performSelector:@selector(getTheRequest:) withObject:@"mySite"];
```

Please note that class names should start from the capital letter and getters should not use the get prefix by Apple's coding standards [Introduction to Coding Guidelines for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000146i)

Answer (score 1):

I think your method is not NSNotificationCenter based what you are trying to do is call a method of your request object.

In that case you would call `request` instead of `self`:

```
request *newRequest=[[request alloc]init];
[request performSelector:@selector(getTheRequest:) withObject:@"mySite"];
```

`NSNotificationCenter` is used like this:

Add observer in your target class:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(getTheRequest:) name:@"getTheRequest" object:nil];
```

Implment the target method:

```
-(void)getTheRequest:(NSString *)string{
  //do something
}
```

And post the notification in the second class:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"getTheRequest" object:@"mySite"];
```

Do not forget to remove the observer in your target class, if you forget it the retain count of your class object will remain 1 and it will not be freed from memory.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"getTheRequest" object:nil];
```